# Holding on a button in iOS should display the title of button

Tags: ios, objective-c

As the title of the question states, when I hold onto a button in iOS,I would like the title of the button to appear. How do I do it? Need some suggestions..

Comment: [button setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Comment: set @"" for all other states and set the string you need as title for UIControlStateHighlighted. this will help

Answer (score 3):

Try this, May be it will help you...

```
[btnName setTitle:@"Your Title" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: this answer is acceptable, there is no any other event that can do so

Comment: please check the next answer by Murali, you failed to add those too, make sure that you make the title nil for all other states

Comment: it doesn't seem to appear in simulator.. only in device is it?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
-(IBAction)BtnTouchdown:(id)sender
{
    mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(showBtnTitle) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];                
}

-(void)showBtnTitle
{
   //use label to show title
}
```

Comment: why so you use timer here? He just need to change the title on highlighting yar!

Comment: "Holding on a button in iOS should display the title of button" not change the title

Comment: You don't need to add a label for that! The UIButton already have a Title display,! Here he can do this by just setting @"" title for all other states and adding text to title only when it is highlighted! Did he mention that he need to show the title as UILabel?? Never! If so, there are several methods to display!

Answer (score 1):

Just set Title for UIControlStateHighlighted only...and for other states there should be no title...

```
[btnName setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[btnName setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btnName setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to appear in simulator.. only in device is it?